# Clear HTTPOnly www.example.com cookie from .example.com Express

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I have recently updated my cookies to use `.example.com` as the domain instead of `www.example.com`.

I have older users out there with a `www.example.com` cookie.

Both have HTTPOnly set so I ca not just run some Javascript to remove them.

I have tried the following but it is not getting the `www.example.com` cookie

```
for(var c in req.cookies){
  res.clearCookie(c, req.cookies[c])
}
```

Any idea on how to clear the `www.example.com` cookie?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably ugly way, but you could try and put a hidden iframe which points to `www.example.com/delwwwcookie` or something and check if you get the cookie in that route's request.

Comment: I've never used iframes - I'm guessing its just an iframe with the src set to that url?

Comment: Yes, just src tag which points to www.site.com/delwwwcookie for example. Then check if you get the cookie in the route handler's request (which you've set to handle the delwwwcookie route).